# Smarty While Nested Loop Show Only First Row

Tags: php, loops, while-loop, nested, smarty

I want to have a category and it's sub-category and i'm using smarty. Here's the code that I use to show the data.

```
global $conn;
$res_groups = array();
$stmt = $conn->prepare("
    SELECT * FROM groups
");
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
while ($group = $stmt->fetch()){
    $groups = array();
    $groupsID = $group['id'];
    $groups['name'] = $group['name'];

    $programs = array();
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("
        SELECT * FROM listings WHERE group_id = '$groupsID'
    ");
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    while ($program = $stmt->fetch()){
        $programs[] = $program;
    }
    $groups['listings'] = $programs;
    $res_groups[] = $groups;
}
```

$smarty->assign('groups', $res_groups);

From that code, I got result like this

```
1. New Group
-- Sub category
-- Sub category
```

What I want is to have all groups that is in my database, and it should be like this

```
1. New Group
-- Sub category
-- Sub category

2. Second Group
-- Sub category
-- Sub category

3. Third Group
-- Sub category
 (and so on for Group 4,5,6)
```

Someone can help me out from this problem?

Comment: It would probably be helpful to see your template code.  And maybe even the output of `var_dump($res_groups);` after the outer `while` loop.

Comment: my data is too long to post in here. Where should I post?

Comment: If you are talking about the output of the `var_dump()`, just limit your queries to only return, say, 2 or 3 rows.  If you are talking about the template, just show the relevant part where you are attempting to produce the desired result mentioned above.  All relevant information to your question should be included _within the question itself_, not off-site

Comment: here you go https://pastebin.com/9aRiX22J

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a day searching for an answer, I found my own answer. Here is the working code

```
global $conn;
$res_groups = array();
$stmt = $conn->prepare("
    SELECT * FROM groups
");
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
while ($group = $stmt->fetch()){
    $groups = array();
    $groups['id'] = $group['id'];
    $groups['name'] = $group['name'];
    $groups['type'] = $group['type'];
    $groups['description'] = $group['description'];
    $groups['sort'] = $group['sort'];
    $groups['status'] = $group['status'];
    $groups['listing_reg_type'] = $group['listing_reg_type'];
    $groups['listing_per_page'] = $group['listing_per_page'];
    $groups['listing_fee'] = $group['listing_fee'];
    $groups['listing_reinvest__fee'] = $group['listing_reinvest_fee'];

    $programs = array();
    $stmts = $conn->prepare('
        SELECT * FROM listings WHERE group_id = "'.$groups['id'].'"
    ');
    $stmts->execute();
    $stmts->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    while ($program = $stmts->fetch()){
        $programs[] = $program;
    }
    $groups['listings'] = $programs;
    $res_groups[] = $groups;
}
```

hope this help others